# Ruby percent-macro (a la %q, %x, %w) for list of integers?

Tags: ruby, macros

I couldn't find a way to define a list of integers using Ruby's macros [in this list](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#generaldelimitedinput).

Is this my only option?

```
%w(123 456).map { |i| i.to_i }
```

I would think `%i(123 456)` would be included, but I guess not.

Comment: How's `%i(123 456)` significantly better than `[123, 456]`? For strings you don't have to type quotes. Are you too lazy to type even commas? :)

Comment: Here's a shortcut, BTW: `%w[123 456].map(&:to_i)`

Comment: `%i(123 456)` would be worse. There is no `Symbol#to_i`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's more of a style issue. Not sure why it was left out if strings, regexes and shell commands were included. See [tadman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17928782/881224), I think they understood my question better than I did! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The utility methods like that are there to handle quoting and escaping issues, neither of which are present in lists of numbers.

For example, handling cases where both quotation styles are used:

```
'Johnny\'s dad\'s friend said, "I really hate backslashes!"'
%Q{Johnny's dad's friend said, "I really hate backslashes!"}
```

For lists of strings:

```
[ 'this', 'that', 'and', 'the', 'other', 'thing' ]
%w[ this that and the other thing ]
```

For regular expressions where slashes occur frequently:

```
/https?:\/\/([\w\-]+).com\//
%r{https?://([\w\-]+).com/}
```

When defining lists of numbers, though, there's no specific escaping required.